# Perl regex to remove nodes in XML

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I have a large (>2gb) XML file that looks roughly like this:

```
<record id="1">
    <a>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <b>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </b>
    <c>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
</record>
...
<record id="999999">
    <a>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <b>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </b>
    <c>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
</record>
```

However, my actual file ***doesn't have line breaks for each node*** (although there are a few line-breaks scattered randomly throughout.)

I would like to have use Perl to remove all of the `<b>` nodes in ***each*** `<record>` node, including their descendants.

So - my resulting file would look like this:

```
<record id="1">
    <a>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <c>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
</record>
...
<record id="999999">
    <a>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <c>
        <detail>blah</detail>
        ....
        <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
</record>
```

***Here's an important note...*** As I mentioned, the file is about 2.4gb. With smaller files, I've used XMLReader and PHP to successfully parse the files and extract what I needed. However, it seems as though PHP can't handle files this large (PHP < v.5.6 uses 32-bit file pointers). So, my goal is to use a utility like `sed` or `perl` to slim down the files by stripping out big chunks that I don't need. I'm aware of "XML-aware" utilities that would be better suited to this type of job, but I haven't found one that can handle files this large...

Anyway, I tried this (using `@` as my delimiter):

```
perl -pe  's@<b>.*</b>@@sg' input.xml > modified.xml
```

But that didn't work - it didn't remove any nodes at all.

I'm sure that the `<b>` nodes don't have any attributes that would break the pattern.

Obviously - I'm a noob when it comes to this, so I'm sure I'm not even close...

Comment: I would recommend using an actual XML Parser like [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Comment: `s@<b>.*</b>@@sg` should have removed from the first `<b>` to the very last `</b>`. It didn't remove anything? Might be the command line Perl options. Normally though, you'd use a lazy quantifier in this circumstance, like `s@<b>.*?</b>@@sg` Even doing this, formatting would be destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<b>(((?!<\/b>).)*)<\/b>
```

Try this.Replace by

.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/2

Comment: Make sure the dot-all modifier is set.

Answer (score 6):

[XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ATwig) can be used to cut elements from a large XML file without having to worry about whitespace between elements:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'record/b' => sub { $_->cut() }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented'
);
$twig->parse($xml);
$twig->print();

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <record id="1">
        <a>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </a>
        <b>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </b>
        <c>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </c>
    </record>
    <record id="999999">
        <a>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </a>
        <b>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </b>
        <c>
            <detail>blah</detail>
            <detail>blah</detail>
        </c>
    </record>
</top>
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
  <record id="1">
    <a>
      <detail>blah</detail>
      <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <c>
      <detail>blah</detail>
      <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
  </record>
  <record id="999999">
    <a>
      <detail>blah</detail>
      <detail>blah</detail>
    </a>
    <c>
      <detail>blah</detail>
      <detail>blah</detail>
    </c>
  </record>
</top>
```

Comment: you can also use xml_grep, which comes with XML::Twig, I think (it's too late for me to test it) that `xml_grep -v 'record/b' file.xml > new_file.xml` would work

Comment: Given the size of the file (~2GB) would it be appropriate to talk about [processing in chunks](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#XML::Twig-101)?

Comment: @miller yes, you're reading the whole file in memory, actually simply doing `XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'record/b' => 1 }, twig_print_outside_roots => 1)->parsefile( "file.xml")` would output the whole file (because of `print_outside_roots`, while omitting the `b` elements). Section 4.5 of the tutorial at http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/tutorial/yapc_twig_s4.html describes this.

Answer (score 3):

Yo ucan use this regex:

```
<b>[\s\S]+?<\/b>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wU4lE7/1)**

[image]

The idea is to remove `<b>...</b>` tags

Comment: why `[\s\S]` and not `.` (with the `s` modifier to the regexp)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader), a libxml2 pull parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $r = 'XML::LibXML::Reader'->new( location => 'file.xml' );
while ($r->nextElement('record')) {
    my $rec = $r->copyCurrentNode(1);
    for my $del ($rec->findnodes('b')) {
        $rec->removeChild($del);
    }
    print $rec;
}
```